# std::swap between std::shared_ptr<A> where A has dynamic array

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmove

first, my code:

```
struct A {
  A(int size);
  ~A();

  A(A&& other);
  A& operator=(const A& other);
  uint8_t* data = nullptr;
};

A::A(int size)
{
  data = new uint8_t[size];
}

A::~A()
{
  delete [] data;
  data = nullptr;
}

A::A(TPixel &&other)
{
  data = other.data;
}

A& A::operator=(const A& other)
{
  data = other.data;
}
```

I have two variable

```
std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>(5);
std::shared_ptr<A> b = std::make_shared<A>(5);
```

I tried `std::swap(a, b);`
 and found error in valgrind:
`std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_move_constructible<A*>, std::is_move_assignable<A*> >::value, void>::type std::swap<A*>(A*&, A*&)`

Why I get this error?
I have implemented move operators and when I tested std::is_move_assignable and std::is_move_constructible the return value was true.

Comment: You have not declared a move assignment operator. Also, in your move constructor, you don't tell the other object *not* to free `data` when it is destroyed, so you'll get a duplicate free.

Comment: And the copy constructor. ...And the copy assignment operator you have should probably copy the underlying data.

Comment: Fix the broken move and copy operations so you don't run into the same bugs later, but you might be better off providing your own `std::swap` overload that swaps the internal pointers.

Comment: Throw this away, and replace it with `struct A { A(int size) : _data(size) {} uint8_t* data() { return _data.data(); } private: std::vector<uint_t> _data; };` and you get correct copy and move for free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> found error in valgrind:
>   `std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_move_constructible<A*>, std::is_move_assignable<A*> >::value, void>::type std::swap<A*>(A*&, A*&)`
>
> Why I get this error?

What you show is not an error. It is a function declaration.

> I have implemented move operators

You have not implemented a move assignment operator.

---

P.S.

- You haven't defined the move constructor.

  - You have defined a constructor that you didn't declare: `A::A(TPixel &&)`. This may be related.
- The copy assignment operator

  - leaks memory.
  - leaves both objects pointing to the same array.
- The destructor has undefined behaviour if the object has been copy-assigned and the copy has already been destroyed.